# Linking to background images

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

I wanted each small image I put over the main background to be linkable. The problem is that they are also referred as backgrounds in the code (don't know how to do it other way). Is there a way to make each one of them clickable with a different link inside? Thanks in advance.

```css
    body,
    html {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
    }

    body {
     background-image: url("https://78.media.tumblr.com/c00202bad8ae39931e34a7efa861d18b/tumblr_p70bjja6xI1x5vw3ao1_500.png"),
     url("https://78.media.tumblr.com/c00202bad8ae39931e34a7efa861d18b/tumblr_p70bjja6xI1x5vw3ao1_500.png"), 
    url("https://78.media.tumblr.com/c00202bad8ae39931e34a7efa861d18b/tumblr_p70bjja6xI1x5vw3ao1_500.png"), 
    url("https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/yI9FRzo/vertical-pan-of-red-lentils-on-white-background-2-this-video-was-shoot-using-custom-light-set-up-with-additional-custom-build-underneath-light-system-to-eliminate-shadows_nkcfxbgmx__F0000.png");
      height: 15%, 10%, 20%, 20%;
      background-position: 397px 30%, 540px 17%, 683px 30%, 0px 0px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 5%, 5%, 5%,cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the small images as elements by adding them into the body tag as

```
<body>
    <div id="smallimg1" class="smallimg">
        <a href="yourlinkhere" target="_blank">
            <img src="linktoimghere.jpg" alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you really want them to be backgroundimages instead of img, then add them as the background of your div and add the backgroundimage, as well as a height and width via css.

Comment: thank you I'm doing it as <div> can you tell me how to change position and scale with this code?

Comment: For position please see the w3c reference on the topic: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp Scaling can be changed by setting a width and height to your elements, either to every .smallimg via the class if they should all be the same size, or via the id #smallimg1 if they are all different size.

Answer (score 0):

Create `<div></div>`'s in your HTML, each div having its own background-image, then organize them as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be css url?

Another solution is by creating it in html and then style it otherwise

```
 An image as a link: <a href="https://link.com">
<img border="0" alt="img" src="logo.jpg" width="100" height="100">
</a>
```